# New line in submit value in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button and the text shall in two lines. This is working in Firefox&Chrome, but not in IE:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="This is a very long 
two line Text" class="submit_button" >
```

CSS:

```
.submit_button {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6AKG/1/

Any ideas for IE (I tried IE11)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use

http://jsfiddle.net/g6AKG/2/

```
.submit_button
{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a button instead.

```
<button type="submit" class="submit_button">
    This is a very long<br>
    two line Text
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="submit" class="submit_button">
    This is a very long<br>
    two line Text
</button>
```

**Edit:** Looks like user Telic and I submitted the same answer seconds apart.